# Laravel use sum with a few conditions

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a Sale model with `price`, `quantity` and `status` attributes

I want to return the total income from the sales table (the query below returns the result I want)

```
SELECT SUM(case when status = 1 then price * quantity when status = 2 then price * quantity * -1 else 0 end) as total
FROM sales;
```

I tried using `select(DB::raw())` but it didn't return a number since I couldn't use the `sum()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a **Sale** model, try something like :

```
$result = Sale::select(DB::raw('SUM(case when status = 1 then price * quantity when status = 2 then price * quantity * -1 else 0 end) as total'))
    ->get();
```